# Magento 2 JS reCaptcha in phtml file

Tags: magento2.3

I have a js

```
<div id="RecaptchaField" class="RecaptchaField"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit" async 
defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var CaptchaCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField', {
        'sitekey': '6Ldo38kZAAAAAJqvMJMI2R79PHy0fjVDU3QMVHKC'
    });
};
</script>
```

How can I write it in a phtml file in Magento 2

i have try

```
 requirejs([
    'jquery'
], function($) {
    var CaptchaCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField', {
        'sitekey': '6Ldo38kZAAAAAJqvMJMI2R79PHy0fjVDU3QMVHKC'
    });
};
$('body').load(CaptchaCallback );
})
```

Comment: try this https://magently.com/blog/recaptcha-in-magento-custom-form/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following link :-

**https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-google-recaptcha-to-magento-2/**

And you want to get extension check this link :-

**https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-google-recaptcha**

**`THANKS.`**